# Why doesn't C++ detect when out of range vector elements are accessed with the [ ] operators by default?

Tags: c++, vector, indexoutofboundsexception

I understand that arrays are a primitive class and therefore do not have built in methods to detect out of range errors.  However, the vector class has the built in function .at() which does detect these errors.  By using namespaces, anyone can overload the [ ] symbols to act as the .at() function by throwing an error when a value out of the vector's range is accessed.  My question is this: why is this functionality not default in C++?

EDIT: Below is an example in pseudocode (I believe - correct me if needed) of overloading the vector operator [ ]:

```
Item_Type& operator[](size_t index) { // Verify that the index is legal.
if (index < 0 || index >= num_items) {
   throw std::out_of_range
     ("index to operator[] is out of range");
}
 return the_data[index]
}
```

I believe this function can be written into a user-defined namespace and is reasonably easy to implement.  If this is true, why is it not default?

Comment: C++ doesn't want everybody to pay the penalty of the checks for mistakes of a few developers.

Comment: *By using namespaces, anyone can reprogram the [ ] symbols to act as the .at() function* - how do you do that?

Comment: "a few" developers - riiiiiight.

Comment: Where did `the_data` come from? That function certainly won't bind to instances of `std::vector`.

Comment: The example was written in pseudocode.  Hence the use of `num_items` instead of `.size()`.

Comment: Your example makes no sense, pseudocode or otherwise. `operator[]` must be a member function, so you cannot just define it at namespace scope. Even if you could, why would your `operator[]` suddenly become a more viable candidate than `vector::operator[]` when invoked on a `vector` instance?

Comment: It may help to look at a simple example: `for (size_t i = 0, n = container.size(); i < n; ++i) use(container[i]);` - we know damned well that the `container[i]` accesses are safe because we've bounded the iteration between `0` and `size()-1` - it would be totally useless and wasteful of code segment memory and CPU cycles to bounds-check every single `container[i]` operation. C++ lets the programmer decide when to pay for these checks (by using `.at(n)` instead of `[n]`).

Comment: @TonyD: That's actually not such a great example. The compiler can hoist the bounds check.

Comment: @MSalters: that typically depends on whether the container provides an inline `operator[]`, which is almost certain for Standard Library containers, but deliberately avoided by some 3rd party libraries (typically to ensure they can be updated by re-linking without client recompilation, or because they've higher complexity/overheads in e.g. locking such that inlining isn't useful). Anyway, if you've an equally simple and more widely applicable example do hit us with it and I'll delete mine....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something that's normally as cheap as `[]`, bounds checking adds a significant overhead.

Consider

```
int f1(const std::vector<int> & v, std:size_t s) { return v[s]; }
```

this function translates to [just three lines of assembly](http://goo.gl/px4Ele):

```
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    movl    (%rax,%rsi,4), %eax
    ret
```

Now consider the bounds-checking version using `at()`:

```
int f2(const std::vector<int> & v, std:size_t s) { return v.at(s); }
```

This becomes

```
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    movq    8(%rdi), %rdx
    subq    %rax, %rdx
    sarq    $2, %rdx
    cmpq    %rdx, %rsi
    jae .L6
    movl    (%rax,%rsi,4), %eax
    ret
.L6:
    pushq   %rax
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)
```

Even in the normal (non-throwing) code path, that's 8 lines of assembly - almost three times as many.

Comment: The question then becomes: How good is your optimizer at removing redundant bounds checks if they can be inlined? :)

Comment: That's awesome - I'm curious as to how you translated this.

Comment: @brandaemon Click on the link :)

Answer (score 3):

C++ has a principle of only pay for what you use. Therefore unchecked operations definitely have their place; just because you're too lazy to be careful about your bounds doesn't mean I should have to pay a performance penalty.

Historically array `[]` has been unchecked in both C and C++. Just because languages 10-20 years younger made that a checked operation doesn't mean C++ needs to make such a fundamental backward-incompatible change.

Comment: Strictly speaking, any implementation can bounds-check their arrays if they choose to do so -- accessing memory off the end of an array is undefined behavior; and a valid implementation of undefined behavior would be to deterministically terminate the program. It wouldn't be a backwards incompatible change.

Comment: So the answer is because `[ ]` is more efficient than `.at()`?  Less calculations are performed, leading to better performance?

Comment: @brand: Yes, doing zero work is more work than doing some work.

Comment: @brand: Sorry, I mean "doing zero work is **less** work than doing some work"

Comment: More importantly, it's possible to add safety on top of speed if necessary, but you can't add speed on top of safety.